# Create a DIV onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` and a `button` which are laid out fine. When I click the button, how can I make the same div spawn again and again. I have tried adding an `onclick` function but I do not know how I would implement adding the div to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="note" contenteditable="true">
    <span id='close' contenteditable='false' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
        <img src="images/close.png" height="25" width="25" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
    </span>Keep clicking this text to select
</div>

<a href='#' class='button'>Create Note</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".note").resizable();
        $(".note").keyup(function() {
            $(this).css('height', '100%');
        });
        $(".note").draggable()
            .click(function() {
                $(this).draggable({
                    disabled: false
                });

            }).dblclick(function() {
                $(this).draggable({
                    disabled: true
                });
            });

    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.note {
    width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-family: Note;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-image: url("images/stickynote.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}

.note img{
    position:relative;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}


.button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 160px;
    margin-left: 44%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #f2ad24;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff92), to(#f2ad24));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92 0%, #f2ad24 100%);
    padding: 13px 26px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
    text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Note;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
    text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
    background: #f08d24;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffe194), to(#f08d24));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194 0%, #f08d24 100%);
    color: #212121;
}

.button:active {
    text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
    border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
    background: #f09424;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffe194), to(#f08d24));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194 0%, #f09424 100%);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: updated there you go

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/xggtfhyx/?

Comment: yes yes thats it. but one problem is that i cant move/drag the new clones EDIT i fixed it

Comment: did you get a fix for this? I see you already have an answer marked. did that work for you?

Comment: incase the answer didn't work for you, you can try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xggtfhyx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can use `jQuery` accomplish what it is you're trying to do.  Obviously this is not exactly tailored to your needs, but will give the basis for you to learn how it might work.  You're likely going to want to look at the [jQuery Clone method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [jQuery AppendTo method](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

**CSS**

```
.note {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('.note:last').clone().appendTo('.wrapper');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="note">Content in div</div>
</div>
<button>Add note</button>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1mx5g452/2/)

Comment: i tried this and it worked but the copy didn't have the same function as the original div. I wanted the button to create a duplicate of the original div.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var html = $('.template').html();
        $('#notes').append('<div style="position:relative;">'+html+'<div>');
    });
})
```

```css
.note img{
position:relative;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}


.button {
position: fixed;
top: 160px;
margin-left: 44%;
border: 1px solid #000000;
background: #f2ad24;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff92), to(#f2ad24));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92, #f2ad24);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff92 0%, #f2ad24 100%);
padding: 13px 26px;
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 0px 0;
text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
color: #000000;
font-size: 35px;
font-family: Note;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover {
border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
background: #f08d24;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffe194), to(#f08d24));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f08d24);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194 0%, #f08d24 100%);
color: #212121;
}
.button:active {
text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
background: #f09424;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffe194), to(#f08d24));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194, #f09424);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffe194 0%, #f09424 100%);
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notes">
<div class="template" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="note" contenteditable="true"> <span id='close' contenteditable='false' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
        <img src="images/close.png" height="25" width="25" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
    </span>Keep clicking this text to select</div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href='#' class='button'>Create Note</a>
```